# Convert dates to NA depending on valid values corresponding to that specific date

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

Let's say I have

```
> df
    fu1_date fu1_n_symp   fu5_date fu5_n_symp   fu7_date fu7_n_symp
1 2012-03-05          1 2014-03-05         NA 2016-03-05          1
2 2013-08-09          1 2015-10-09          2 2017-11-09         NA
3 2019-05-05          1 2020-06-07          2 2021-07-09          2
```

`df` denotes an extremely large dataframe. In this example, I have recorded the number of symptoms `n_symp` on different follow-up dates `fu_date`.

There are up to 20 follow-ups for each row in my dataframe, `fu1_`, `fu2_`, ... , `fu20_`. I need to correct my dataframe, so that if `n_symp` is `NA` then the corresponding `fuX_date` should be converted from `as.Date()` to `NA`.

You can see that `row 1` had missing values in follow-up 5 (`fu5_n_symp == NA`), but not FU1 or FU7. Consequently, `fu5_date` in row 1 should be converted from `2014-03-05` to `NA`

I am looking for a solution in `dplyr` only.

**Expected output**

```
> df
    fu1_date fu1_n_symp   fu5_date fu5_n_symp   fu7_date fu7_n_symp
1 2012-03-05          1       <NA>         NA 2016-03-05          1
2 2013-08-09          1 2015-10-09          2       <NA>         NA
3 2019-05-05          1 2020-06-07          2 2021-07-09          2
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(fu1_date = structure(c(15404, 15926, 18021), class = "Date"), 
    fu1_n_symp = c(1L, 1L, 1L), fu5_date = structure(c(16134, 
    16717, 18420), class = "Date"), fu5_n_symp = c(NA, 2L, 2L
    ), fu7_date = structure(c(16865, 17479, 18817), class = "Date"), 
    fu7_n_symp = c(1L, NA, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pivot_longer()`, you can specify `".value"` to `names_to` to stack `date` and `n_symp` pairwise. In this case, one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern` must be supplied to specify how the column names should be split. Then you can easily replace those dates with `NA` where `n_symp` are missing. Finally, pivot the long data wider to get the original format.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("fu", ".value"), names_sep = "(?<=\\d)_") %>%
  mutate(date = replace(date, is.na(n_symp), NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fu, values_from = c(date, n_symp),
              names_glue = "{fu}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest")

# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#      id fu1_date   fu1_n_symp fu5_date   fu5_n_symp fu7_date   fu7_n_symp
#   <int> <date>          <int> <date>          <int> <date>          <int>
# 1     1 2012-03-05          1 NA                 NA 2016-03-05          1
# 2     2 2013-08-09          1 2015-10-09          2 NA                 NA
# 3     3 2019-05-05          1 2020-06-07          2 2021-07-09          2
```

`names_vary` in `pivot_wider()` controls in what order should the resulting column names be combined.

- "fastest" (default)

  ```
  fu1_date   fu5_date   fu7_date   fu1_n_symp fu5_n_symp fu7_n_symp
  ```
- "slowest"

  ```
  fu1_date   fu1_n_symp fu5_date   fu5_n_symp fu7_date   fu7_n_symp
  ```

Comment: This is a very good idea!

Answer (score 3):

Upate: Tweaked code after @Darren Tsai input:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id,
               names_to = "key",
               values_to = "val", 
               values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>% # change all to character class
  mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(lead(val, default = val[1])), NA_character_, val)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= key, values_from = val) %>% 
  type_convert() %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Here is one way how we can do it, using pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "key",
               values_to = "val", 
               values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>% # change all to character class
  mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(lead(val, default = val[1])), NA_character_, val)) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= key, values_from = val) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date)) # to get back to date class
  select(-row)
```

```
  fu1_date   fu1_n_symp fu5_date   fu5_n_symp fu7_date   fu7_n_symp
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 2012-03-05 1          NA         NA         2016-03-05 1         
2 2013-08-09 1          2015-10-09 2          NA         NA        
3 2019-05-05 1          2020-06-07 2          2021-07-09 2
```

Comment: Maybe `type_convert()` is needed to turn each column back to its initial type. (The output is all character now)

Comment: good idea but it's not recommended to stack columns with different types. In this case you stack `int` and `Date` together and convert into `character`. What if some column is the real number with floating points, merging it with a character column will lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you ask for a `dplyr` solution. On the other hand, you also write that you have an *extremely large dataframe*. Therefore, for future reference, I think it may be worth considering a `base` solution, which is faster.

```
do.call(cbind,
        setNames(
          lapply(split.default(df, (seq_len(ncol(df)) + 1) %/% 2), \(d){
            d[[1]] = replace(d[[1]], is.na(d[[2]]), NA)
            d
          }), NULL))

#     fu1_date fu1_n_symp   fu5_date fu5_n_symp   fu7_date fu7_n_symp
# 1 2012-03-05          1       <NA>         NA 2016-03-05          1
# 2 2013-08-09          1 2015-10-09          2       <NA>         NA
# 3 2019-05-05          1 2020-06-07          2 2021-07-09          2
```

---

##### Benchmark

Prepare some larger data (certainly not "extremely" large):

```
d = setNames(cbind(df, df, df, df, df, df, df),
             paste0(paste0("fu", rep(1:21, each = 2)),
                    "_", c("date", "n_symp")))

n = 1e6
d2 = d[rep(1:nrow(d), n), ]
dim(d2)
# [1] 3000000      42
```

`dplyr` 1 (TarJae):

```
system.time({
  d3 = d2 %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-id,
                 names_to = "key",
                 values_to = "val", 
                 values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>% # change all to character class
    mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(lead(val, default = val[1])), NA_character_, val)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from= key, values_from = val) %>% 
    type_convert()
})

# n = 1e6
#   user  system elapsed 
# 423.76   13.02  445.55
```

`dplyr`2 (Darren Tsai):

```
system.time({
  d4 = d2 %>%
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("fu", ".value"), names_sep = "(?<=\\d)_") %>%
    mutate(date = replace(date, is.na(n_symp), NA)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = fu, values_from = c(date, n_symp),
                names_glue = "{fu}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest")
})

# n = 1e6
#  user  system elapsed 
# 21.34    2.28   23.73

# n = 1e7
#   user  system elapsed 
# 293.25  441.64  871.64
```

`base`:

```
system.time({
  d5 = do.call(cbind,
               setNames(
                 lapply(split.default(d2, (seq_len(ncol(d2)) + 1) %/% 2), \(d){
                   d[[1]] = replace(d[[1]], is.na(d[[2]]), NA)
                   d
                 }), NULL))

})

# n = 1e6
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.28    0.11    1.39 

# n = 1e7
#  user  system elapsed 
# 11.43   16.79   35.72

all.equal(d3, d4)
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(as.data.frame(d3[ , -1]), `rownames<-`(d5, NULL))
# [1] TRUE
```

Thus, for `n = 1e6`, the `base` alternative is about 300 and 15 times faster, respectively, than the `dplyr` code. It also seems to scale better; for `n = 1e7`, the `base` alternative is ca. 24 times faster than the fastest `dplyr`.